Sample ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API in GitHub codespaces
How can I make this sample ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API work in GitHub spaces?
Code space: https://bookish-space-chainsaw-4jgw4575jvvhqg5g.github.dev/
GitHub: https://github.com/xmione/Codespaces.API
I can build and run it using dotnet build and dotnet run commands but I get an HTTP ERROR 404 when I try to browse it.

The github doc gives the guidance of starting the .net app , https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/setting-up-your-dotnet-project-for-codespaces Try with .net8 version.
